# Locally extracting DBpedia Spotlight annotations from HTML files with Java API

Tags: dbpedia, spotlight-dbpedia

Can I directly convert my HTML file to a DBpedia annotated file using the Java API? I found a related question:

- [using dbpedia spotlight in java or scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10658485/using-dbpedia-spotlight-in-java-or-scala)

but this is sends the text to web service; instead I need to convert locally.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the parameter text to send an html content such as :

`<html><body> Hackers from the Syrian Electronic Army claimed responsibility for re-directing links sent by President Barack Obama to a pro-Assad video</body></html>`

E.g:
http://spotlight.sztaki.hu:2222/rest/annotate?text=%3Chtml%3E%3Cbody%3E%20Hackers%20from%20the%20Syrian%20Electronic%20Army%20claimed%20responsibility%20for%20re-directing%20links%20sent%20by%20President%20Barack%20Obama%20to%20a%20pro-Assad%20video%3C/body%3E%3C/html%3E

Do not forget to use [POST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29) instead of [GET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GET_%28HTTP%29#Request_methods)!